# Swift Wrongly Reading PFQuery Return

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift2, parse-server, pfquery

I have PFQuery function in Swift that's supposed to act based on the returned objects. I've tried if error == nil, if objects != nil and if error == nil && objects != nil, but it always acts as if the keys "otherUser" and "responded" were equalTo what the query asked for, although "otherUser" is not found in the class "Requests" and "responded" equals to "False".  (I shortened the actual full-length query because it was too long).

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Requests")
        query.whereKey("otherUser", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectForKey("username") as! String)
        query.whereKey("responded", equalTo: "True")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil && objects != nil{
                print(objects)
                print("disabling confirm button")
                self.stopTime = self.defaults.integerForKey("intKey")
            }else{
                print("Did not respond yet.")
                self.counter = 1200
                self.storyboard
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: Are you supposed to be comparing `responded` to a string, rather than boolean?

Also, this query should not return `object == nil` unless `error != nil`.  In the event that no objects are found that match this query, you should return an empty array, not nil. Is that what's happening, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if `otherUser` is not found or `responded` is False, `query` still will NOT return error, and `objects` will just be an empty array. And an empty array is not nil, it exists in the heap.

So as long as you are doing everything right, even if the query does not match your constraint, it still returns an empty array instead of an error.

If you want to check if the query has returned any results, you can use `if (objects.count)` to check if the returned results is empty or not.